# LAMBDA with a table that that is used in JOIN mutliple times

Tags: c#, sql-server, join, lambda, multiple-tables

I currently have this has my JOIN and WHERE clause

```
cotr.Join(_contract,
          p => p.ContractRefNo,
          x => x.RefNo,
          (p, x) => x)
    .Join(_person2,
          x => x.COTREmployeeId,
          p2 => p2.EmployeeId,
          (x, p2) =>  p2 )
    .Where(p => p.RefNo == _refno);
```

The "cotr" and "_person2" are the same table.  In once instance I join the cotr to a contracts table based on a field.  IN a second join I join the _person2 table to the contracts table on another field.  I know for sure there are some results because when I run this sql code I in SSMS I get the correct record back.

```
SELECT  Personal_a.pp_refno
        , Personal_a.pp_empid
        , Personal_a.pp_userid
        , Personal_a.pp_pwd
        , Personal_a.pp_title
        , Personal_a.pp_voice
        , Personal_a.pp_lname
        , Personal_a.pp_fname
        , Personal_a.pp_city
        , Personal_a.pp_state
        , Personal.pp_dos
FROM    dbo.personal Personal 
JOIN    dbo.contracts Contracts 
    ON  Personal.PP_Contract = Contracts.cn_refno 
JOIN    dbo.personal Personal_a 
    ON  Contracts.cn_coempid = Personal_a.pp_empid
WHERE   Personal.pp_refno = 90221
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.  Can anyone take a look at this and give me a hand?

Comment: see msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  See left outer join.

Comment: @jdweng The OP is not doing a Left outer join in there SQL.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize `cotr`, `_contract`, and `_person2`.  Also the column names in your SQL and Linq code do not match up so could you also show your entity definitions.

Comment: 'var _contract = dal.ContractRepository.GetAll();
var _person2 = dal.PersonalRepository.GetAll();
var cotr = dal.PersonalRepository.GetAll();'